# Login on facebook using username and password. Is there any way to do that?

Tags: facebook

I have a mobile application where I want the user to send to the server his facebook credentials infos and the server will act in behalf of him in facebook (get friends list and so on).
I am researching about it, but I only find information about this oauth2, where the user logs himself in Facebook in a special link, so my app can access his FB information. This doesn't help me because I would like to access this information on the server side, not by the app itself. Is there any way that I can log in using username and password?

I have a WP7 application for facebook chat where I enter my username and password and I connect, so it should be some way to perform it, correct?

**edit**
Because it is against the TOS, I am thinking about doing the following:
My server sends to my client the URL so the user can login and allow my app to access its informations. After that, my server accesses it.
Would that be possible?

Comment: I believe that this is not legal and will get you in REAL troubles, please refer to the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies): > You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or **collects
> Facebook usernames or passwords**.

Comment: Hi, this is not for a serious app and will not be published.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB is removing the `offline_access` token.

No solution for this question i guess.

No offline_access, token expires in 60days, No access with username and password(AGAINST TOS)

Answer (score 1):

This is against their tos, but you could use

```
<?php

/* EDIT EMAIL AND PASSWORD */
$EMAIL      = "";
$PASSWORD   = "";

function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

$a = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,null,"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);
$c = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,$b[1],"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);
for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++)
    $cookie.=$d[1][$i].";";

/*
NOW TO JUST OPEN ANOTHER URL EDIT THE FIRST ARGUMENT OF THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION.
TO SEND SOME DATA EDIT THE LAST ARGUMENT.
*/
echo cURL("http://www.facebook.com/",null,$cookie,null);
?>
```

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/290893

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! thanks a lot!
I will test it tomorrow and give you some feedback!

Comment: -1, while this is a programming Q&A website...but providing an answer without checking all the aspects of the question (even in terms of guidelines and policies) is not *professional* (and I'm not that it's ethically accepted!)

Comment: The script didn't work and, as @ifaour mentioned, it is not allowed. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ifaour: I know it's not allowed by their TOS. Yes, I forgot to add it to my answer, added

Answer (score 1):

A solution you could use that is TOS friendly would be to have the user sign up on your website and grant the offline_access token using the Facebook SDK. Your mobile app could use that token to make requests on behalf of the user in you mobile app.  I would be clear as your requesting the permission with what you intend to with it.