# manual login facebook using username and password

Tags: facebook, authentication, manual

I know it was mentioned before that it violates Facebook policy
and it was mentioned here:
[Facebook Login by sending User Name and Password from my Database Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366384/facebook-login-by-sending-user-name-and-password-from-my-database-table)
[Login on facebook using username and password. Is there any way to do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167802/login-on-facebook-using-username-and-password-is-there-any-way-to-do-that)

I will use it as a personal site to protect my password from being entered at computers that doesn't belong to me.

Is it possible to simulate the browser from server ?
Is there a way to use cookies even?

Answer (score 0):

phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/), slimerjs (http://slimerjs.org), or a similar technology can do this for you, you can simulate full browser including the rendering engine with these tools.

However, if it violates Facebook rules and gets you banned there's probably a better overall approach to look at.